# AWS EC2 instance types supported by EMR

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-emr

I need to retrieve a list of EC2 instance types supported by EMR. I collected the list of all ec2 instance type for a particular region using this

```
        AmazonEC2 ec2Client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                .build();
        DescribeInstanceTypesRequest describeInstanceTypesRequest = new DescribeInstanceTypesRequest();

        do{
            DescribeInstanceTypesResult describeInstanceTypesResult = ec2Client.describeInstanceTypes(describeInstanceTypesRequest);

            for (InstanceTypeInfo instanceTypeInfo : describeInstanceTypesResult.getInstanceTypes()) {
                
                    instances.add(instanceTypeInfo.getInstanceType());
               
            }
            describeInstanceTypesRequest.setNextToken(describeInstanceTypesResult.getNextToken());
        } while (describeInstanceTypesRequest.getNextToken() != null);
```

Not all of these instance type are supported by EMR. Is there a way to filter out only those that are supported by EMR?